# Creating default object from empty value in laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

when i try to use bellow controller function the the error that Creating default object from empty value is raised how can i fix it??

```
savemed($id,$pid,$tid){
    $meds=TemporyMed::all();

    foreach($meds as $med){

    $issued_medicine=new IssuedMedicine();
    $issued_medicines->treatments_id=$tid;
    $issued_medicines->type=$med->type;
    $issued_medicines->quantity=$med->quantity;
    $issued_medicines->price=$med->price;
    $issued_medicines->save();


 }

 TemporyMed::all()->delete();

}
```